# Passing a method result of component A to the template of Component B

Tags: angular, typescript

Getting back to Angular after five years I am struggling with this issue:

I have a function returning a list in my first component, this function is triggered by clicking on a button:

Component A :

Template A :

```
java script<button name="pay" routerLink="/payment" (click)="function()">Pay</button>
```

Module A:

```
function()

{
   return list;
}
```

Now my question is how could I display the result of `function()` in the template of my second component B? Is there an Angular mechanism for that? I guess inter class event binding?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean Angular and not AngularJS, since you wrote `(click)="function()"` and not `ng-click="function()"`. Feel free to rollback my edit if I was incorrect.

Comment: As far as the question goes, I would use a service for this.

Comment: Is component A and B related (child or parent) ? If yes which one is the child and which one is the parent ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, no I did not set any inheritance between A and B we are rather in a suite of components.

Comment: @HereticMonkey my understanding of services is to link the app with external feeder. In my cas I am linking two components I am reading an article about emitters. I guess that's the solution. However I am not sure it will work inside a return?

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer to my questions, indeed as this concerns unrelated components I have to use a service.